# Changing size image in Oracle window and problem with Script Output

Tags: oracle, image, window, size, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have some aesthetic problems in Oracle SQL Developer.

First is **moving the Script Output window**. It seems to me it could have been moved on screen area. But some time I kinda moved the window somewhere and now I can't move it.

[image]

Second matter is that **images moved from files explorer are unfitted to my preferences** (I mean dimensions). Is here remaining solution is only to resize images in Paint and then moving to Oracle? Maybe these things are nothing for you but I can't stand mess on my screen.

[image]

Third screenshot showing my curiousal but annoying problem related with 2nd question. As you can see - the scale of this image is too high. I'd like to have whole image on some not too big area. But now I have bad-scaled image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't move the Script panel around, however the images looks like you're moving the SQL Worksheet, which contains the script output.

You can do that. IF you want to make it look 'all normal' or reset to the default desktop layout, use the Window menu, and choose this -

[image]

'Reset Windows to Factory Settings' - this refers to the SQL Developer windowing layout, not your OS, so it's safe.

SQL Developer UI will disappear, and repaint after a moment or two, hopefully back to 'normal.'

I'm sorry, I don't understand your 2nd question re: preferences and paint...

Comment: In 2nd question I meant dimensions window containing some image (f.e. to creating some tables, sequences, whatever you want basing on image - I mean some layouts and relations). Of course, in one moment my screen shows worksheet, Script Output and some other elements. But when I move image in original size from file explorer to Oracle app I can't zoom out an image, now I must look for layout details with slider. I can only change window dimensions.
I mentioned about Paint because now only remaining option to look on code and image in one moment is just editing image dimensions in Paint.

Comment: Are you meaning the screen isn't rendering correctly? What screen exactly are you showing in your 2nd screenshot?

Comment: I added 3rd picture showing my problem to post and some description.

Comment: That 3rd picture isn't SQL Developer...or you're going to need to tell me exact how you got there.

Comment: You're wrong. It's exactly Developer. I just moved a sample picture from my files explorer to ease my sql learning, just not to switching between sql developer and image preview. It's just not problem but I'd like to make my learning easier

Comment: @baobab159 I VERY well could be wrong, but...exactly WHERE are you dropping a picture from your file explorer? What editor/feature are you using to view the image?

Comment: and @baobab159 did my answer help you with your first issue?

Comment: It helped. I'm dropping a picture just to SQL Developer. I just press chosen picture and move hold picture. You can be surprised but yes, that apps reads pictures as you see

Comment: @baobab159 you now know more than me it seems, I have no idea how you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: Ha It's simple, it's like sending a photo to private message on Facebook. You save a file f.e.on desktop and move to message box on Facebook. It's intuitive. I can't explain it simpler. But the truth is I'm total beginner in sql so maybe looking at the photo is only on programming start